# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

Hello so i'm new to typescript react and currently trying to make applications using typescript and tutorial from youtube.

```
const RegisterCustomer: React.FC = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState<string>('');

    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
    const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('');
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
    const { register } = useAuth();
    
    

  return (
   <IonPage>
        <Register />
        <IonContent className="body">
        <IonGrid className="gridinput1">
        
        </IonGrid>

        <IonGrid className="gridinput2">
        <IonRow>
            <IonInput type="email" className="inputEmail" value={email} placeholder="Email" onIonChange={e => setEmail(e.detail.value!)}></IonInput>
        </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
        <IonGrid className="gridinput3">
        <IonRow>
            <IonInput type="password" className="inputEmail" value={password} placeholder="Password" onIonChange={e => setPassword(e.detail.value!)}></IonInput>
        </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
        <IonGrid className="gridinput1">
        <IonRow>
            <IonButton onClick={async e =>{
                e.preventDefault()
                register(email, password)
                .then((res) => console.log(res))
                .catch((err) => console.log(err))
            }} className="buttonLogin" expand="block" size="default" color="new">
                Register Now
            </IonButton>
        </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>   
            <p className="loginSeller"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Are you a seller? Login as Seller</a></p>
    </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default RegisterCustomer;
```

i'm trying get the data in register to firebase but i encounter error in register.then it says

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
```

how do i solve this problem

Comment: Please edit the question to state what you've done to debug this already.  You should be able to narrow this down to the single line of code that causes the problem, and understand what is the thing that's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a null conditional operator before your .then i.e.

```js
register(email, password)?
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

it is just that question mark after the call to register. It means only execute the .then if the value is not null or undefined

also you may want to explicitly handle a null value:
i.e.

```js
const res = await register(email, password);
if(res) {
    console.log(res);
}
else {
    //handle null response
}
```

edit: I am assuming useAuth is a function that returns an object containing async function register

Comment: This is the AuthContext
```
export const useAuth = () =>useContext(AuthContext);
type AuthContextType = {
    currentUser: null;
    register: (
      email: string,
      password: string
    ) => Promise<UserCredential | undefined>;
  };
export default function AuthContextProvider( { children}  : ButtonProps){
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    function register(email: string, password:string) {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    }

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        register,
    }
   
}
```